# How to implement vlookup cross referencing with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, vlookup

### Given the Following DataFrames

1. `jg`

```py
 Job  Group
   1  116.0
   2  116.0
   3  116.0
   4  116.0
   5  116.0
   6  116.0
   7  124.0
   8  124.0
   9   74.0
  10   74.0
  11   74.0
  12  126.0
  13  126.0
```

2. `ul`

```py
 UpperGroup  LowerGroup  Time
        116         116     5
        116         124    15
        116          74    15
        116         126    15
        124         116    15
        124         124     5
        124          74    15
        124         126    15
         74         116    15
         74         124    15
         74          74     5
         74         126    15
        126         116    15
        126         124    15
        126          74    15
        126         126     5
```

### Desired Result

- The following table is produced with an Excel `vlookup`

1. The colors are for reference

   - The Grey filled area isn't needed in the DataFrame result
2. I'm trying to create a DataFrame / Table where the `'Job'` numbers from `jg` are the column and the index.

   - The `'Group'` value for the `'Job'` number in the columns, should be used to reference `'UpperGroup'` from `ul`
   - The `'Group'` value for the `'Job'` number in the index, should be used to reference `'LowerGroup'` from `ul`
3. The values are `'Time'` from `ul` corresponding to `'UpperGroup'` and `'LowerGroup'`.

   - `'UpperGroup'` = 116 and `'LowerGroup'` = 224, map to `'Time'` = 15

[image]

### Reproducible DataFrames

```py
import pandas as pd

ul_data = {'UpperGroup': [116, 116, 116, 116, 124, 124, 124, 124, 74, 74, 74, 74, 126, 126, 126, 126],
           'LowerGroup': [116, 124, 74, 126, 116, 124, 74, 126, 116, 124, 74, 126, 116, 124, 74, 126],
           'Time': [5, 15, 15, 15, 15, 5, 15, 15, 15, 15, 5, 15, 15, 15, 15, 5]}
ul = pd.DataFrame(ul_data)

jg_data = {'Job': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
           'Group': [116.0, 116.0, 116.0, 116.0, 116.0, 116.0, 124.0, 124.0, 74.0, 74.0, 74.0, 126.0, 126.0]}
jg = pd.DataFrame(jg_data)
```

### Research

- I have reviewed several of the questions from the search, but they don't really seem to fit, and I just can't think of a way to bring it all together.

  1. [Google - pandas vlookup site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas%20vlookup%20site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=ALeKk03XmnrVRBJ7h2hj9kd3S_NHsEsxgg:1616640689028&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjPp_7vt8rvAhV0NX0KHaziALkQrQIoBHoECAYQBQ&biw=1920&bih=977)
  2. Considered `merge/join`
  3. Considered `map`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to get the desired results.

```
ul.set_index(['UpperGroup', 'LowerGroup'])['Time'].unstack().reindex(index=jg['Group'], columns=jg['Group'])
```

Output:

```
Group  116.0  116.0  116.0  116.0  116.0  116.0  124.0  124.0  74.0   74.0   74.0   126.0  126.0
Group                                                                                           
116.0      5      5      5      5      5      5     15     15     15     15     15     15     15
116.0      5      5      5      5      5      5     15     15     15     15     15     15     15
116.0      5      5      5      5      5      5     15     15     15     15     15     15     15
116.0      5      5      5      5      5      5     15     15     15     15     15     15     15
116.0      5      5      5      5      5      5     15     15     15     15     15     15     15
116.0      5      5      5      5      5      5     15     15     15     15     15     15     15
124.0     15     15     15     15     15     15      5      5     15     15     15     15     15
124.0     15     15     15     15     15     15      5      5     15     15     15     15     15
74.0      15     15     15     15     15     15     15     15      5      5      5     15     15
74.0      15     15     15     15     15     15     15     15      5      5      5     15     15
74.0      15     15     15     15     15     15     15     15      5      5      5     15     15
126.0     15     15     15     15     15     15     15     15     15     15     15      5      5
126.0     15     15     15     15     15     15     15     15     15     15     15      5      5
```

Going further:

```
ul.set_index(['UpperGroup', 'LowerGroup'])['Time']\
  .unstack()\
  .reindex(index=jg['Group'], columns=jg['Group'])\
  .set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(jg[['Group', 'Job']]))\
  .set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(jg[['Group', 'Job']]), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
Group     116.0                     124.0     74.0          126.0    
Job          1   2   3   4   5   6     7   8     9   10  11    12  13
Group Job                                                            
116.0 1       5   5   5   5   5   5    15  15    15  15  15    15  15
      2       5   5   5   5   5   5    15  15    15  15  15    15  15
      3       5   5   5   5   5   5    15  15    15  15  15    15  15
      4       5   5   5   5   5   5    15  15    15  15  15    15  15
      5       5   5   5   5   5   5    15  15    15  15  15    15  15
      6       5   5   5   5   5   5    15  15    15  15  15    15  15
124.0 7      15  15  15  15  15  15     5   5    15  15  15    15  15
      8      15  15  15  15  15  15     5   5    15  15  15    15  15
74.0  9      15  15  15  15  15  15    15  15     5   5   5    15  15
      10     15  15  15  15  15  15    15  15     5   5   5    15  15
      11     15  15  15  15  15  15    15  15     5   5   5    15  15
126.0 12     15  15  15  15  15  15    15  15    15  15  15     5   5
      13     15  15  15  15  15  15    15  15    15  15  15     5   5
```